# Customized spring boot controller to support exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am in trouble with overwriting default spring boot controller. Reason has to do that is to support customized exception handling, i.e. post with invalid object, update at invalid index, delete at invalid index, etc.

But the more I dive into my own controller, the more thing I found myself need to fix:

1. Adding _links.self.href in every object, although spring-hateoas can do me a favor there is still a lot of work needs to be done.
2. Support paging and sizing. Again, a lot of work.

I started wondering if above two points could remain unchanged while having my own exception handling.....

Answer (score 1):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler {
    private Logger logger = getLogger(CommonExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    public String methodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException e) {
        logger.error("receive unsupported method: {}", e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    }
}
```

---

I don't know if this is what you need.
`HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class` can be replace with any `Throwable` class or interface, even `Throwable.class` itself, also your custom exception.
And after handled the exception, you can return any restful result or view (example is a view: `/error` page).

More information: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc